# Angular2, toggle a checked checkbox list

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Is there a way to toggle a checked checkbox list in Angular2?

I have a button that when pressed and the full list is in view, it will show only the checked items in the list.  When the button is pressed again, it will show the entire list.

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/jZz4XoHjYJ40bjt2eOU5?p=preview

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
       <li *ngFor="let col of data" class="form-group">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="col" value="{{col.value}}" [(ngModel)]="col.value" (change)="addColumns(col)" />{{col.name}}
                                    </li>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  data:any[]=[{"id":"13","name":"AAA"},{"id":"15","name":"BBB"},{"id":"20","name":"CCC"}]
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
  get selectedcheckboxes() {
    return this.data
      .filter(opt => opt.value)  

  }

  addColumns(col){
    this.selectedcheckboxes;
    console.log(this.selectedcheckboxes)
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule,FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <my-app>
    loading...
  </my-app>
  <button class="check">Collapse/Expand</button>
  </body>
```

In Angular1, it looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/of4yy8k9/ I'm looking to do the same thing in Angular2, but can't understand the syntax.

Comment: you mean to say. when button is pressed, you want to unchecked all the checked checkbox

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers No, when I press the button, it will show the list of only checked boxes, when I press the button again, it will re-show the entire list of checked boxes (both checked and unchecked)

Comment: So you want two functionality on same button, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but hopefully there's an easy way to toggle back and forth because in Angular 1, it's pretty simple: http://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/of4yy8k9/

Answer (score 1):

You can put the main array in other variable and then just change the data variable according your clicked button (to expand or to collapse), you may need one variable to define if it's full list or the selected list

something like:

```
isFullList: boolean;
mainData: Array<any> = [your main data here];
data: Array<any> = [data to use in list]; //should initied by mandata
toggle() {
    //this.isFullList: boolean

    if (!this.isFullList) {
      this.data = [...this.mainData];
    } else {
      this.data = [...this.selectedcheckboxes];
    }
    console.log(this.data)
    this.isFullList = ! this.isFullList
}
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/V1iiX87gYVMUtIkmpMfT?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can implement an filter at your component, and invoke the filter at your template.

In the filter, just add a flag to control to filter or show original list, and toggle the flag by click the button.

Invoke filter at template

```
*ngFor="let col of getData()"
```

Filter data in component

```
getData() {
  return this.filter ? this.data.filter(item => item.value === true) : this.data;
}
```

**[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/3YnokuRt9nrxJZKSQGUG?p=preview)**